# Category theory: identifying abstract structures from concrete categories

Tags: category-theory

In p.150 of "Conceptual Mathematics 2nd. ed" we are told:

> An abstract structure type often arises from a particular example as follows. Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ is a small family of objects and maps in a category $\mathbf{X}$, with the domain and codomain of any map in $\mathbf{A}$ being in $\mathbf{A}$. Let each object $A$ in $\mathbf{A}$ be considered as the name of '$A$-shaped figures' and each map $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{A}$ be considered as a name $\alpha^{*}$ of structural map. The domain of $\alpha^{*}$ is the codomain of $\alpha$, and the codomain of $\alpha^{*}$ is the domain of $\alpha$. Then every object $X$ of $\mathbf{X}$ gives rise to an $\mathbf{A}$-structure whose $A$-th component set is the set of all $\mathbf{X}$-maps $A \rightarrow X$ and wherein for each $\alpha: B \rightarrow A$ the structural map on these figures has for all $x$, $\alpha_{X}^{*}(x) = x \circ a$.
>
> Show that every map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathbf{X}$ gives rise to a map in the category of $\mathbf{A}$-structures by the associative law.

I don't even know where to begin with this.. I assume the proof structure goes something like:

$ f \circ \alpha_{X}^{*}(x) = f \circ (x \circ \alpha) = (f \circ x) \circ \alpha = ??? = y \circ (\alpha \circ f) = (y \circ \alpha) \circ f = \alpha_{Y}^{*} \circ f$

Knowing only $f: X \rightarrow Y$ I don't see how the domains/codomains line up, or what that ??? should be.. any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, something like that. Your $y$ will be simply $f\circ x$, and then it is about only:
$$f(\alpha_X^*(x))\ =\ f\circ x\circ\alpha\ =\ \alpha_Y^*(f\circ x)\,.$$

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now - thanks!